# Finding an angle in a kite

Tags: geometry, angle

I feel like this shouldn't be this hard, but nothing on the internet seems to have helped at this point. I'm using a leg stretcher (which has 3 bars, 2 holding my legs, and a center one to pull to my crotch) with a belt to train my splits and wanted to know the angle between my legs (and see how I've improved). **All given units are in centimeters.**

Using my legs and the stretcher, I get a kite:

$\overline{AB} = \overline{AD} = a = 76$
(Stretcher Bars)

$\overline{BC} = \overline{CD} = b = 80$
(Legs)

$\overline{AC} = f = 57 + s$
(Center bar + belt)

$s = \{35, 30.5, 27, 25\}$
(Belt lengths)

I'm trying to find the angle $\gamma$ (located at C, so between the 2 b sides) and the length of $\overline{BD}$

I'd prefer an explanation or formula as I want to use the formula again later ($s$ - the belt - will get smaller and smaller after all).

Any help is appreciated. (in the picture I used $\mu$ and $d$ for the desired angle and side ($\mu$ only since I don't have the greek letters on my keyboard, but I do have this)
[image: Visualization of Kite, with sides and points]

Comment: You can use Pythagoras theorem to solve for length $d$ using lines $AB$ and $AO$. Then double it to reflect the side over $AC$, you can then use the cosine law to solve for γ. So, $2d^2 = 80^2 + 80^2 - 2 \times 80 \times 80 \times \cos{γ }$, where you can now solve for γ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The figure is left right symmetric in $AC$

Cosine Law for triangle $ABC$ gives...
$$ 
\cos( \frac \mu 2)= \frac{b^2+(s+f)^2-a^2}{ 2b(s+f)}
$$
Let $O$ be the point in the middle.

Then $COB$ is a right angled triangle with hypotenuse $b$ for which...
$$
\sin( \frac \mu 2)= \frac d{2b}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $AB = AD$ and $CB = CD$ there is a reflection symmetry of the kite with respect to the vertical diagonal $AC$ and so the two triangles $\Delta \, ACD$ and $\Delta\, ACB$ are congruent and the diagonal $AC$ is perpendicular to the diagonal $BD$. $ $ Also $\angle\, DCA = \angle\,BCA = \frac{1}{2}\,\angle\, DCB = \frac{\mu}{2}$. If $Q = AC \, \cap \, BD$ then $DQ$ is the height of the triangle $\Delta\, ACD$.

In the right-angled triangle $\Delta \, ACQ$ you have $$ \sin\left(\frac{\mu}{2}\right) \, = \,\frac{DQ}{CD}$$

Since you have $AD = a, \, CD = b$ and $AC = f$, then you can use Heron's formula to calculate the area of $\Delta \, ACD$

$$\text{Area}(\Delta \, ACD) \, =\, \frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\,(a + b + f)(a + b - f)(a - b + f)(-a + b + f)\,}$$

and write the area equation $$\text{Area}(\Delta \, ACD) \, = \, \frac{1}{2} \, AC \cdot DQ \, = \, \frac{1}{2} \,f \,DQ $$ so you get to calculate the height segment $DQ$ as follows

$$DQ \, =\, \frac{2 \, \text{Area}(\Delta \, ACD)}{f} \, =\, \frac{\sqrt{\,(a + b + f)(a + b - f)(a - b + f)(-a + b + f)\,}}{2\,f}$$

From here, you can calculate the angle $\mu$ as follows

$$\sin\left(\frac{\mu}{2}\right) \, = \,\frac{DQ}{CD} \, =\, \frac{DQ}{b} \, = \, \frac{\sqrt{\,(a + b + f)(a + b - f)(a - b + f)(-a + b + f)\,}}{2\,b\,f}$$

Finally,
$$\mu \, =\, 2\,\arcsin\left(\, \frac{\sqrt{\,(a + b + f)(a + b - f)(a - b + f)(-a + b + f)\,}}{2\,b\,f}\,\right)$$
$$BD \, =\, \frac{\sqrt{\,(a + b + f)(a + b - f)(a - b + f)(-a + b + f)\,}}{f}$$

I wrote this python script that calculates what you want

```
import numpy as np

def Heron(a,b,c):
    return np.sqrt((a+b+c)*(a+b-c)*(a-b+c)*(-a+b+c))/4

def angle_and_length(a,b,f):
    Area = Heron(a,b,f)
    BD = 2 * Area / f
    sin_half = BD / b
    return 2*np.arcsin(sin_half)*180/np.pi, 2*BD

a = 76
b = 80
s = np.array([35, 30.5,27,25])
f = 57+s

print('angles (in degrees): ')
print(angle_and_length(a,b,f)[0])
print('')
print('diagonals: ')
print(angle_and_length(a,b,f)[1])
```

And the output is

```
angles (in degrees): 
[103.7482341  107.48056304 110.30019084 111.87997057]

diagonals: 
[125.86499203 129.01508721 131.30428906 132.55222221]
```